# Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect DECIMAL valu

Tags: sql, mariadb, warnings

I have a problem with the following SQL script, where I received the warning "#1292 Truncated incorrect DECIMAL value".

All the fields are VARCHAR.
I tried with the cast in CHAR but nothing.
I Tried by removing the
`AND cast(substring_index(substring_index(nomefilepdf, '_', 12), '_', -1) as int) = 0` but nothing.
I noticed that if i remove the AND operator from the WHERE clauses the warning dissapear, so I think is not a problem with decimal's values.

```
  INSERT INTO `BOP_APPENDICI`(RAMO, RISCHIO, PREMIO)            
SELECT 
substring_index(substring_index(nomefilepdf, '_', 10), '_', -1) as ramo_view,
substring_index(substring_index(nomefilepdf, '_', 11), '_', -1) as rischio_view,
substring_index(substring_index(nomefilepdf, '_', 12), '_', -1) as premio_view
FROM `BOP_importazioneAppendici
WHERE 
substring_index(substring_index(nomefilepdf, '_', 4), '_', -1) IN 
    (SELECT TIPO_DOC FROM BOP_DOMINIO_DOCUMENTI)
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM BOP_DOMINIO_RAMO_RISCHIO d
    WHERE 
        d.ramo = substring_index(substring_index(nomefilepdf, '_', 10), '_', -1)
        AND d.rischio = substring_index(substring_index(nomefilepdf, '_', 11), '_', -1)
)
AND cast(substring_index(substring_index(nomefilepdf, '_', 12), '_', -1) as int) = 0
```

Comment: While debugging, skip the INSERT for a while and do the SELECT alone. Still an error? Then see what happens if you move the WHERE clause expressions to the SELECT list. Do the returned data look fine/weird/unexpected/valid/invalid/etc?

Comment: what do you mean by "remove the AND operator"?  that would get you a syntax error.  show that query, please.  also, please copy and paste your actual query, what you have here has other problems, presumably from editing or retyping it.

Comment: what does `select nomefilepdf from BOP_importazioneAppendici where substring_index(substring_index(nomefilepdf,'_',12),'_',-1) = 0 limit 10` show?

Comment: the warning absolutely does mean that something is being treated as a number that isn't one.  could be the cast, could be the d.ramo= or d.rischio= if those are numeric types.  possibly one of your values has fewer _ than you expect (in which case your substrings will get from after the last _)?

Comment: Show us a sample string and the datatype in the table.

Answer (score 0):

In the last line you're casting it as integer:

```
AND cast(substring_index(substring_index(nomefilepdf, '_', 12), '_', -1) as int) = 0
```

If I understood correctly, by removing this AND-clause you don't get the error because it's not trying to cast a char as int anymore.

Are you sure the column you're casting as integer is composed only of numbers?

Comment: I removed also the last line that you shared but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

My answer it's only to try help you to debug your problem:

```
SELECT DISTINCT substring_index(substring_index(nomefilepdf, '_', 12), '_', -1)
FROM BOP_importazioneAppendici
WHERE
    cast(substring_index(substring_index(nomefilepdf, '_', 12), '_', -1) as int) = 0
    AND nomefilepdf NOT REGEXP '^[0-9]+$';
```

Running this query should find the records that give you problems, so you can better understand the problem. Let me know if this help you